# Pandas: Replace values of multiple columns using boolean masks

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, indexing

**Question**: Given DataFrame `b`, how can I replace the values of multiple columns, with one value, through boolean mask column identification?

**What works, but I don't want:**

```
b.iloc[:, 2:6] = "someConstantValue"
```

**What doesn't work, but I want:**

```
b.iloc[:, 2:6][b["columnA"] == "someCondition"]] = "someConstantValue"
```

Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) and for columns names by positions use indexing by `b.columns[2:6]`.

```
b = pd.DataFrame({'A':list('abaaef'),
                   'B':[4,5,4,5,5,4],
                   'C':[7,8,9,4,2,3],
                   'D':[1,3,5,7,1,0],
                   'E':[5,3,6,9,2,4]})

print (b)
   A  B  C  D  E
0  a  4  7  1  5
1  b  5  8  3  3
2  a  4  9  5  6
3  a  5  4  7  9
4  e  5  2  1  2
5  f  4  3  0  4

b.loc[b["A"] == "a", b.columns[2:6]] = 100
print (b)
   A  B    C    D    E
0  a  4  100  100  100
1  b  5    8    3    3
2  a  4  100  100  100
3  a  5  100  100  100
4  e  5    2    1    2
5  f  4    3    0    4
```

Comment: "100 loops, best of 3: 3.26 ms per loop". Compared to @ysearka "100 loops, best of 3: 2.98 ms per loop", with modification on his/her response. Check comment.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `iloc` with Boolean indexing, but be careful. It works with Boolean **arrays**, not Boolean series. For example:

```
b.iloc[(b['A'] == 'a').values, 2:6] = 'someConstantValue'
```

As an aside, chained indexing is [explicitly discouraged](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#why-does-assignment-fail-when-using-chained-indexing) in the docs. There should never be a need to use chained indexing.

Comment: 10 secs late  ;]

Comment: "100 loops, best of 3: 2.65 ms per loop". Too late bud ;)

Comment: Could you elaborate further concerning chain indexing?

Comment: Also, how does your solution filter for multiple conditions of 'A'?

Comment: Not sure what you mean. Your example and jezrael's solution, as well as mine, all filter for a single condition only.

Comment: @Neel, For chained indexing please follow the link in my answer.

Comment: @jpp In this case, (b['A'] == 'a').values, where a is the only condition for filtering. How would your solution change if there are 'a', 'b', 'c'...'z' conditions to be met?

Comment: As an example: `(b['A'].isin(['a', 'b', 'c'])).values`